# giving border for columns other than first column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've a HTML code where i want the column border to be starting from second column. and my code is as below.

```html
<table class="frame_PD-all">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left" valign="top">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="font-style-bold">B.1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="9" align="center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">GENERAL COMMENCEMENT OF A CAUSE OR MATTER</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left" valign="top">
        <div class="para"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">1.</div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top">
        <div class="para">On sealing a writ for that commencement of an action or filling a counterclaim</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">400</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">00</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="font-style-italic">Praecipe</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left" valign="top">
        <div class="para"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">2.</div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top">
        <div class="para">On sealing an originating summons</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">160</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">00</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="font-style-italic">Praecipe</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left" valign="top">
        <div class="para"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">3.</div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top">
        <div class="para">On sealing a concurrent or renewed writ or a concurrent or renewed originating summons</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">20</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">00</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="font-style-italic">Praecipe</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left" valign="top">
        <div class="para"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">4.</div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top">
        <div class="para">On sealing an amended writ or an amended originating summons</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">20</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">00</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="font-style-italic">Praecipe</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left" valign="top">
        <div class="para"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">5.</div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top">
        <div class="para">On sealing any other form of commencement of a cause or matter where no fee is specifically provided</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">160</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">00</div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-center" valign="top">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="font-style-italic">Praecipe</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

The fiddle is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLjFY/4/)**.

How i can start the column border from second column. i.e. here in this case `B1` should be out of the border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child()` pseudo selector for that

```
table.frame_PD-all tr>td:nth-child(n+2){
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/HbgDA/2/)

For more detail visit [**HERE**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-child)

To avoid the space between cells you can use `border-collapse` property

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/HbgDA/3/)

Comment: Good answer, I like this one. +1

Comment: Hi @Pranav: this solution is working great, but I've got another problem, I've 2 tables one as `<table class="frame-none">` and other as `<table class="frame_new-none">` when i apply the above css the rule is getting applied for both the tables, is there a way where i can use this only for `<table class="frame_new-none">` table. Thanks again.

Comment: use `table.frame_new-none tr>td:nth-child(n+2)` selector. table tag followed by a `.` and the class name without any space

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the :first-child selector?

```
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid left;
}
table tr td:first-child {
    border: none;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp